# Why does Win32 console cursor stop blinking after making the console full screen?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a Win32 console that is in full screen (windowed). Whenever it is in full screen, I noticed that the console cursor stopped blinking. It just stays as a blank line. I can type with it just fine. It just does not blink for some reason.

It starts off like this...

```
Console con("My Console"); 
con.setFullScreen(true); 
con.setFontSize(24); 

con.write("Enter your name: ");
std::string name = con.readLine();
```

I narrowed down that the problem is in setFullScreen(true).

This is the code used in that function (specific to full screen):

```
bool Console::setFullScreen(const bool fullScreen, const bool showScrollBarState, 
    const bool hideMouseCursor)
{
    HWND handle = getHandle();
    LONG style;

    if (fullScreen)
    {
        // Set the window style
        style = GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE);
        style &= ~(WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME);
        SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE, style);

        // Set the window to full screen (windowed mode)
        if (!ShowWindow(handle, SW_MAXIMIZE))
            return false; 
    } else { //…}

    return true;
}
```

I narrowed down to this line:

```
        // Set the window to full screen (windowed mode)
        if (!ShowWindow(handle, SW_MAXIMIZE))
            return false;
```

If I eliminate this line, a borderless window shows a blinking cursor. If I include this line, the cursor stops blinking. If I set it to SW_NORMAL, it shows a borderless console with a blinking cursor.

For reference, getHandle() has the following code:

```
HWND Console::getHandle()
{
    return GetConsoleWindow();
}
```

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Windows 10 either by maximizing the console window or actually making it fullscreen (Alt+Enter). It appears to be a bug in the console's window procedure. If I switch to another window and back, the cursor resumes blinking.

Comment: I'm able to confirm switching windows in Win10 makes the cursor blink again.

Comment: A solution I found for now appears to be call ShowWindow() with SW_MINIMIZE and then call it again with SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED.

Comment: The console window is not yours. It's owned by the console system. Messing with its styles like that is not supported.

Comment: @RaymondChen, granted, but then maybe `GetWindowThreadProcessId` shouldn't lie about who owns a console window. The console tracks its effective owner as window data, which this function returns. If the effective owner exits, the console shifts ownership to the next attached process, until there are no more attached processes, and it destroys itself. Thus if a process calls `AllocConsole` to get a console, according to Windows this process effectively owns the window. Given this white lie, one could take the position that the 'owner' can do whatever it wants with its window.

Comment: @eryksun Indeed, in the old days `GetWindowThreadProcessId` did not lie. It said that the window was owned by the console system. But people asked for the lie (presumably so they could match up console windows to processes) so we gave it to them. It is a lie because you wanted us to lie.

Comment: @RaymondChen, one consequence is that Task Manager and taskkill.exe send `WM_CLOSE` to the console window when killing its owner. Thus all processes attached to the console get a Ctrl+Close event and have 5 seconds to exit, else they're forcefully terminated. It shouldn't have to kill the console session. If a process has no window or only a console window, try to attach to the console and send Ctrl+Close to the process. This would require a `GenerateConsoleCtrlEventEx` function that allows sending Ctrl+Close and takes a flag to indicate whether the given ID is for a process or process group.

Answer (score 2):

As Eryksun pointed out, this appears to be a bug in the WinAPI.

A solution I found for now appears to be call ShowWindow() with SW_MINIMIZE and then call it again with SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED.

For example,

```
// Set the window to full screen (windowed mode)
ShowWindow(handle, SW_MINIMIZE);
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

After that, the cursor blinks again.

Comment: This is *not* a bug in the Windows API. This is a bug in your code. You are using the API outside its documented specification, by messing with a resource you do not own. The system is free to do anything it wants in that case.

Comment: @IInspectable, the cursor-blink bug is not necessarily related to modifying the window style. I reproduced it in Windows 10 with a default console window, just using the maximize button and Alt+Enter fullscreen toggle.

Comment: @eryksun: That still doesn't make it a bug in the API.

Comment: @IInspectable, if you mean literally a bug in the programming interface, then no. But it is quite clearly a bug in the console host application, conhost.exe.

Comment: You can probably keep @IInspectable happy(er) by calling `SendMessage (hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)` rather than using `ShowWindow()`.  The console window will then believe that the user has selected 'Maximize' from the system menu and can decide for itself what it actually wants to do (which might include some housekeeping).  Given the comments above I don't think that this will actually help, but nonetheless it is cleaner.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks for the thought. I tried this but had the same problem.

Comment: @Bob Yes, I'm sure it will do, but it's still the best / most future-proof way (because you're not doing anything from outside the app that the app might not expect).